# row_number resets based on two columns in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My goal is to generate the following `row_number`, called `transaction_in_row`

[image]

The `row_number` should reset based on (`partition_by`) customer and has_transaction column. My issue is on the yellow column, the `row_number` in Bigquery will return 3 instead of 1.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
row_number() over(partition by customer, has_transaction order by month asc) as transaction_in_row
```

Any help will be appreciated and feel free to shoot me any question for more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a gaps and islands problem, one approach to solve it is using the difference of two row_number functions as the following:

```
With tbl_name As (
  Select 'x' As customer, 1 As month, TRUE As has_transaction  Union All
  Select 'x', 2, TRUE  Union All
  Select 'x', 3, FALSE  Union All
  Select 'x', 4, FALSE  Union All
  Select 'x', 5, TRUE  Union All
  Select 'x', 6, TRUE  Union All
  Select 'x', 7, FALSE),
  grps as
  (
    select *,
      row_number() over (partition by customer order by month) -
      row_number() over (partition by customer, has_transaction order by month) grp
    from tbl_name
  )
  select customer, month, has_transaction,
         row_number() over (partition by customer, has_transaction, grp order by month) as transaction_in_row
  from grps
  order by customer, month
```

Output:

[image]